# html5 download attribute works but file renaming doesn't

Tags: html, google-chrome, cross-browser

I've come across certain problems regarding download attribute of html5. What I found is:
It supports download attribute as expected in chrome as well firefox. But the value of attribute don't outcome as expected on both browser.
First on chrome, it doesn't rename file.
On Firefox, it renames but it doesn't include the extension.

```html
<a href="pdf.pdf" download="myfile">Download the file</a>
```

In Firefox, If I do download="myfile.pdf", It works. Shouldn't It work without extension. And What the Problem with Chrome because I read somewhere Chrome supports download property.